# .tfignore path not getting ignored

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-code, azure-devops

I  have the below folder.I need to ignore all folder and file inside target folder .Currenly i am doing like below

```
\abc\cde\my-app-1\target\*
 \abc\cde\my-app-2\target\*
\abc\cde\my-app-3\target\*
```

I will be creating my-app-4 and so on in future and i need to keep adding the path .tfiignore file.How can i create a generic path in .tfignore so i dont have to modify my .tfignore everytime.

I tried below but it didnt  work

```
 \abc\cde\*\target\*
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try add below to the .tfignore to ignore the `target` folder.

`abc\cde\target`

Or

`abc\target`

I have tested above path. They all worked as expected.